# C++ Sfml white square when drawing sprite with framework

Tags: c++, sfml

I am making an sfml framework, in the framework there is a makeSpr() function. The function has the normal code for creating a sprite inside of it, but draws a white square. I have used the texture on a different sprite, which isn't drawn using the function. It draws it normally.

makeSpr() function:

```
sf::Sprite makeSpr(sf::Texture tex, int x,int y, int sizeX,int sixeY) {
    sf::Sprite spr;
    spr.setTexture(tex);
    spr.setScale(sizeX,sizeY);
    spr.setPosition(x,y);
    return spr;
}
```

Use of makeSpr to assign it to a Sprite ():

```
sf::Sprite sprTest = makeSpr(texTxtBox, 100,100, 5,5);
```

Drawing the sprite in the main loop between window.clear() and window.diplay()

```
window.draw(sprTest);
```

The texture works well if I draw it normally without the framework.

```
sf::Sprite sprTxtBox;
sprTxtBox.setTexture(texTxtBox);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `tex` by const reference:

```
sf::Sprite makeSpr(const sf::Texture& tex, int x,int y, int sizeX,int sixeY)
```

When you write `sf::Sprite makeSpr(sf::Texture tex, ...` and call `sf::Sprite sprTest = makeSpr(texTxtBox, ...`, `tex` is actually a copy of `texTxtBox`, and it gets free after `return spr;` in `makeSpr`, hence your `spr` now has an invalid texture (already destroyed), hence it draws only white. What you want is passing `texTxtBox` itself, by passing by (const) reference, and you have to make sure that `texTxtBox` out-live `sprTest`.

Comment: Thanks, had a feeling the texture was erased, but didn't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Kerrot Please, if this answer solves your problem, mark it as solved is encouraged. This help others to find solution to similar problems and will make you and the answerer earn some reputation